# capistrano unicorn can't start my app master failed to start

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, nginx, capistrano, unicorn

I want to deploy my app to ocean digitals droplet, after a few errors in the deploy i figured out, but i have  a new problem my app simply show a blank page, i look into my log files, this is my unicorn log file: http://pastebin.com/5LFJ7avm

i dont know how to continue, i think is something related with `app error: Missing secret_key_base for 'production' environment, set this value in config/secrets.yml (RuntimeError)` but i dont know.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That error means exactly what it says.

There should be a file in approot/config, called 'secrets.yml', which you should add the following to:
    `production:`

`secret_key_base: whatever your secret key for production is here`